# Reloading a table view with an Iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, xml, uitableview, reload

I am using a table view controller that makes a call to a web service and then parses the XML and display it in the table view. The problem is that the first time that I load it the XML apparently is not finished parsing before the view is shown. How can I reload the view after the XML is done parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Call the table view's reloadData method when the parsing has completed.

Answer (score 0):

After parsing is done, call tableview reloadData

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

[mytable reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [datas count];
}
```

Make sure that you update the mutable array "datas" value after parsing, such as datas will have the parsed contents.

[Here](http://theappleblog.com/2008/08/04/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/) is sample program of parsing and displaying the parsed content in table, you can refer it how they are reloading their table after parsing

All the best.